# Flutter arb file spacing in a select translation

Tags: flutter, localization, flutter-localizations, arb

I am trying to translate a list of countries like that:

arb file:

```
"countries": "{choice, select, United States {United States} Mexico {Mexico} other {None}}",
```

The implementation should be like this:

```
S.of(context).countries(countryName)
```

but the issue is it's not detecting two words as a single key when `S.of(context).countries('United States')`

The problem is with the 2 words countries or whatever.